# How to revert a NxN matrix which was read diagonally?

Tags: c, matrix

Suppose if am having one 2D array

I got an array , 'char input[N][N]' which was read diagonally by someone.

My aim is reproduce the original array 'char input_original[N][N]' from the diagonally read 'char input[N][N]' array

After reading diagonally , my input is ,

a d b

c e g -------------------> matrix A

h f i

and now i want to make it as

a b c

d e f -------------------> matrix B (input_original array)

g h i

Where the matrix A is the diagonal read output( a db ceg hf i --> made this as a matrix) of matrix B

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: are you asking for the code or the algorithm? either way, i think one example is not enough..

Comment: What does it mean to "diagonally read" a matrix?

Comment: Algorithm level logic also fine for me.

Comment: @Marshall : Reading diagonally means,  first read a downwards then bd upwards and then ceg downwards and so on..

Comment: If you know how it was read, and what order everything came in, then aren't you already there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just compute the "path" through your matrix if it's diagonal, e.g.

```
1--2  3--4  5
  /  /  /  /|
 /  /  /  / |
6  7  8  9  10
| /  /  /  /
|/  /  /  / 
11 12 13 14 15
   /  /  /  /|
  /  /  /  / |
16 17 18 19 20
|  /  /  /  /
| /  /  /  / 
21 22-23 24-25
```

This is, you store the indices in the order you read them in. After you've done this, you can just fill your matrix according to these indices.

So the most difficult stuff in this case is how to compute the path. You can do this as follows: First of all, we recognize that the path conists exclusively of four directions:

- right (R)
- right up (UR)
- down (D)
- down left (DL)

Furthermore we recognize that only some orders of directions are allowed:

- R-DL
- DL-DL
- DL-D
- DL-R
- D-UR
- UR-UR
- UR-R

Using this knowledge it is no problem to compute the path: We just have to store the last direction and the current position. Then, we have to compute the next direction the following way:

- if the last direction was UR, we try UR, and if that's not possible, we walk R.
- if the last direction was DL, we try DL, and if that's not possible, we walk D, if that's also not possible, we walk R.

I hope I didn't mess anything up, but I think that's quite a practical way to do it.